# how to disable a widget inside a pageview if there is no data

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a pageview with widget1 and widget2 both use a futurebuilder i want to disable widget2 and swipe if there is no data in his futurebuilder

```
body: PageView(
 controller: controller,
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: Column(
                  
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      
                      child: PageView(
                       scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal

                      children: [
                        Widget1(),
                        Widget2()
                      ]),
                    ),
                    Widget3(),

                   
                    Widget4(),

                   
                    widget5(),
                    widget6(),

                   
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: I have two pages 1 and 2. I want to stay only on page 1 and also no swipe if in page2 there is no data in the futurebuilder

Comment: if you have 2 `Future`s then use `Future.wait` on them and show `PageView` when `Future.wait` completes

Comment: each page has its own futurebuilder.page 1 has its own future and page2 has its own future and it's in two different widget

Comment: that's what I said: if you have two futures use `Future.wait` - it will wait for both futures and you will know if you should show 2 or 1  or no page at all

Comment: in which page should I do the future wait page1 or page2 or in the parent page of both do you have an example

Comment: you need one `FutureBuilder` that as an input uses `Future.wait` and as output builds `PageView` that has 1 or 2 pages

Comment: do you have a sample code

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a list containing all widgets to spread in the `PageView()` as shown below.

```
List<Widget> allWidgets = [];

body: PageView(
 controller: controller,
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: Column(
                  
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      
                      child: PageView(
                       scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal

                      children: [
                       ...allWidgets
                      ]),
                    ),
                    Widget3(),

                   
                    Widget4(),

                   
                    widget5(),
                    widget6(),

                   
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

And add your custom widgets which are all have their own  `FutureBuilder()` as you just said to `allWidgets` List. You can do this with `if(snapshot.HasData){}` as you can see in example.

```
class Widget1 extends StatefulWidget {
                    Widget1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
                  
                    @override
                    State<Widget1> createState() => _Widget1State();
                  }
                  
                  class _Widget1State extends State<Widget1> {
                    @override
                    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                      return Scaffold(body: FutureBuilder(
                        future: someData,
                        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
    allWidgets.add(Widget1());
                            return Container();
                          }else{
                            return CircularProgressIndicator();
                          }
                          
                        },
                      ),
                      );
                    }
                  }
```

Comment: thank you for your response how to access the allWidgets list on the other page while keeping the content

Comment: put adwidget if snapshot.hasdata does not work the application refreshes without stopping

Comment: You can make `allWidgets` variable public or use a state management to achieve this. It doesn't work probably you are not obtaining `allWidgets`. Can you share the error you run into?

Comment: the error is when I do allWidgets.add(Widget1()); inside the futurebuilder the application refreshes continuously

Comment: I left another answer, it helps you keep your app running trying to find a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it's not the best practice but you can also do this.

```
class Widget1 extends StatefulWidget {
  Widget1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Widget1> createState() => _Widget1State();
}

Future<dynamic>? some;

class _Widget1State extends State<Widget1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: some, // Don't write this line, leave it as it is.
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Container();
          } else {
            return SizedBox(width: 0, height: 0,);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And don't touch the other widget. `SizedBox` will have no effect on UI.

```
body: PageView(
 controller: controller,
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: Column(
                  
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      
                      child: PageView(
                       scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal

                      children: [

                       Widget1(),
                       Widget2()

                      ]),
                    ),
                    Widget3(),

                   
                    Widget4(),

                   
                    widget5(),
                    widget6(),

                   
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: not working with this approch